# angular reactive form: lose parent when share formControl in multiple formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

When different `formGroups` hold the same `formControl`, only one of them will be notified if the `formControl` change.

`formControl` has a `parent` attr, but not `parents`, when it is added to a `formGroup`, angular will replace its `parent` attr.

```js
const parent1 = new FormGroup({});
const partent2 = new FormGroup({});
const control = new FormControl();
parent1.addControl('key1', control);
parent2.addControl('key2', control);
parent1.valueChanges.subscribe((data)=>console.log('parent1 change'));
parent2.valueChanges.subscribe((data)=>console.log('parent2 change'));
control.setValue('v');
// only parent1 change
```

I need a way to share `formControl` in different `formGroups`. It is very exhausting to copy a `formControl` manually. (copy initial value, copy validators, subscribe valueChanges).
Is there a better way to share `formControl`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `AbstractControl` has an attribute `parent: FormGroup | FormArray` as you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.1.0/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L155). So controls can only have one parent.

The parent is notified in the following way:

```
updateValueAndValidity(opts: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}): void {
   this._setInitialStatus();
   this._updateValue();

   if (this.enabled) {
     this._cancelExistingSubscription();
     (this as{errors: ValidationErrors | null}).errors = this._runValidator();
     (this as{status: string}).status = this._calculateStatus();

     if (this.status === VALID || this.status === PENDING) {
       this._runAsyncValidator(opts.emitEvent);
     }
   }

   if (opts.emitEvent !== false) {
     (this.valueChanges as EventEmitter<any>).emit(this.value);
     (this.statusChanges as EventEmitter<string>).emit(this.status);
   }

   if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {//<------------------------
     this._parent.updateValueAndValidity(opts);
   }
}
```